# TLS for Windows Store and Windows 7+ Desktop

Tags: c++, windows, ssl, network-programming, schannel

I want a client/server C++ application that can use TLS for secure communication, including client certificates, and potential to select and validate certificates myself.

I have used Schannel to do this before, but the key [InitializeSecurityContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375506(v=vs.85).aspx) is marked `[desktop apps only]`.

Have Microsoft provided a new equivalent API?

Although in theory I could replace the whole thing (since in the end, I can still have a normal plaintext TCP socket) I would rather stick to OS components if possible.